# memory growth in opengl

Tags: ios, opengl-es, memory-leaks, paint

I have code for change brush in my paint app. Everything works fine, but I found, that if I call that method many times, memory doesnt free, and grow and grow... And I can't find where is it?

```
- (void)setBrush:(UIImage *)brush withColor:(UIColor *)color andOpacity:(CGFloat)opacity andSize:(CGFloat)size {
CGImageRef brushImage;
CGContextRef brushContext;
GLubyte *brushData;
size_t width, height;
brushImage = brush.CGImage;
width = CGImageGetWidth(brushImage);
height = CGImageGetHeight(brushImage);
if(brushImage) {
    brushData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
    brushContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(brushData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(brushImage), (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextDrawImage(brushContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), brushImage);
    CGContextRelease(brushContext);
    glGenTextures(1, &brushTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, brushData);
    free(brushData);
}
CGColorRef clr = [color CGColor];
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(clr);
CGFloat red = components[0];
CGFloat green = components[1];
CGFloat blue = components[2];
glColor4f(red * opacity/3, green * opacity/3, blue * opacity/3, opacity/3);
glPointSize(width * size / 2);
}
```

where it could be, how it correct?

Comment: did you try using the memory leaks instrument ? it should show the trace and the problematic line. btw if your memory grows it doesn't necessarily means you have a leak.

Comment: yes, I wrote little incorrect title. memory grows, but why? ARC enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never delete the texture you are creating with `glGenTextures()`, so you'll just allocate more and more space to hold all the texture data.

Comment: how can I do it, and where? 
Sorry for stupid question, I'm newby in OpenGL

Comment: @mopsicus You have to delete it via `glDeleteTexture()`, and you need to do it at a place where you no longer need the texture. So before calling `glGenTextures()` would be a good time. Alternatively, you only need to create the texture once, and can update its data anytime you want/need, which should also make the performance a tiny bit better.

Comment: You should also be aware that `glDeleteTextures (...)` does not immediately free memory. This only occurs when 0 references to the texture remain. Ordinarily `glDeleteTextures (...)` will unbind the texture and that is enough to eliminate references and immediately free the memory, but there are some less common situations (e.g. the texture is attached to an FBO or bound in another render context) in which the memory will not be freed until you do some extra work to get rid of the references. This is not usually a big issue, but it is sometimes a head scratcher when tracking used video memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that you are generating a texture with `glGenTextures` on every change of a brush. These textures are kept by `openGL` and must be freed by using the `glDeleteTextures` method once you are done with them.

I recommend you to keep track of the generated texture and just use the binding variable with the `glBindTexture` when you want to use that texture (without generating it again). This binding variable just tells openGL where in memory the texture resides.

Generating and deleting a texture everytime you set a brush might impact performance unless it is not oftenly used.